# Bootloop after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, display-manager

I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -d` today to get the new Ubuntu 18.04. While I was asked if I would keep the current display manager or take the one delivered with the distro the installation interrupted.
So when went to boot my Dell XPS15 I get this loop

1. black screen
2. Terminal message for ~1sec:

   ```
   /dev/nume0n1p1: clean, 1030409/31260672 files, 23204669/125026560 blocks
   ```

this loops all the time.

Here’s what I did so far:

- rebooted multiple times
- removed Nvidia driver
- switched from gdm3 to LightDM (with LightDM I can at least see the login page, but when I try to log in it just brings me back to the login page again...)
- switched to xdm (same like LightDM)
- started Ubuntu in recovery mode and tried to fix all missed packages. Doing this I get the message that there are 5.738 k to download. When I continue each repository-call returns `failed to fetch`. But the network is activated.

I'm running out of ideas, any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Start your system once again in recovery mode an check that you have IP on you network card: `ip a s` and DNS servers are set in `cat /etc/resolve.comf` If yes, ping for example google.pl to check if you have connection to the internet (with working DNSes).

Comment: When I do `ping 8.8.8.8` there a 0 packages lost, looks good...

Comment: Does anyone knows what's behind the recovery option "dpkg - Repair broken packages"? Can I manually call this in command line?

Comment: "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to continue half-configured packages, "sudo apt-get install -f" to fix broken packages

Comment: Thanks @L.S. but in my case there are differences: When I use the revocery repair tool it shows me ~140MB to download. When boot to login screen and log in to terminal (CTRL + ALT + F2) and type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` there are no updates. I dont understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally booted ubuntu live and used the reinstall option. This works great if you use exactly the same username and password.

Comment: Yea you can also seperate the /home and the / partition so you won't loose data or settings on reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 is using gnome, so i assume your display manager is gdm now. There are 2 versions of the graphical backend for the gdm: Xorg and Wayland. Depending on how old your Graphics-Driver from nvidia is, it won't run with Wayland. If you removed your nvidia-driver, it will still try to load because you may need to configure your xconfig to run noveau-driver again.

Comment: I tried both, Gnome XOrg and Wayland. I also have KDE installed, same result (returns to login screen).

Comment: What does dmesg tell you after you get returned to the login screen? you switch to a shell with ALT+F2 or any other F-Key lower than 7 and switch back with ALT+F7. In the console you can log in an run dmesg or logs in /var/logs/... Maybe there are 2 different problems

Comment: when i do dmesg the main errors and exceptions are ACPI AE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @kernification that means the ACPI implementation of your BIOS has problems. This is mostly done due to windows compatibility i guess. However this should not prevent your PC from booting or entering the Desktop. Is there anything else of interest? Alternatively you can also look into /var/log/syslog (cat /var/log/syslog)

Comment: thanks, I have also found `No input driver specified, ignoring this device. [    12.316] (II) This device may have been added with another device file. [    12.316] (II) config/udev: Adding input device (unnamed) (/dev/tty10)`. And there is also no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file... maybe this is the issue? In X11 i only see a lot of xorg.conf."randomnumber" files.

Comment: if you install the nvidia driver with apt-get you will also want to install and run nvidia-xconfig. It will write an xconfig file for you automatically with the nvidia driver inserted.